# Hibernate converto to org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I'm using hibernate (spring-boot) to persit data in SQL Server.

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
private LocalDateTime data;
```

Data post 1/1/1893 is saved correctly. Data before 1/11/1893 is saved with wrong hours, minutes and seconds. Probably hibernate fail to convert from PersistentLocalDateTime to java.sql.Date.

How can i solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: perhaps take a look at [AttributeConverter](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters)s? it seems like you need a simple `LocalDateTime.parse(yourString, "d/M/yyyy")`.

Comment: Hi Using PersistentLocalDateTimeAsString seem to sovle the problem. But i get the error

Comment: what error do you get? please give as much information as possible on your question!

Comment: Sorry.  Using PersistentLocalDateTimeAsString seem to solve the problem. But i get the error  when i load a record nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
Invalid format: "1750-11-11 00:10:04.0" is malformed at " 00:10:04.0"; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1750-11-11 00:10:04.0" 
is malformed at " 00:10:04.0"]